# XCode App Stuck on Launch Screen No Error Log

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I use XCode 8.1 and using Swift 3. 
The app suddenly decided to stuck on the launch screen when I run it from XCode with no error log. I put breakpoint in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but it isn't triggered. The app doesn't shut itself completely, just keeps displaying the launch screen. Interesting thing is that when I tap the app on the device without XCode, the app works with no problem. Any idea why this is happening?

What I tried

- Removed Derived Data
- Restart XCode
- Restart the computer
- Uninstall the app
- Clean/Build

Below is what I get when it crashes.

```
APPNAME`main:
0x1000c6fc4 <+0>:   stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
0x1000c6fc8 <+4>:   mov    x29, sp
0x1000c6fcc <+8>:   sub    sp, sp, #32               ; =32 
0x1000c6fd0 <+12>:  adrp   x8, 1366
0x1000c6fd4 <+16>:  ldr    x8, [x8, #2272]
0x1000c6fd8 <+20>:  adrp   x9, 1366
0x1000c6fdc <+24>:  ldr    x9, [x9, #1472]
0x1000c6fe0 <+28>:  str    w0, [x9]
0x1000c6fe4 <+32>:  ldr    x8, [x8]
0x1000c6fe8 <+36>:  cmn    x8, #1                    ; =1 
0x1000c6fec <+40>:  stur   w0, [x29, #-4]
0x1000c6ff0 <+44>:  str    x1, [sp, #16]
0x1000c6ff4 <+48>:  b.eq   0x1000c7010               ; <+76> at AppDelegate.swift:17
0x1000c6ff8 <+52>:  adrp   x8, 1366
0x1000c6ffc <+56>:  ldr    x0, [x8, #2272]
0x1000c7000 <+60>:  adrp   x8, 1365
0x1000c7004 <+64>:  ldr    x8, [x8, #2264]
0x1000c7008 <+68>:  mov    x1, x8
0x1000c700c <+72>:  bl     0x1004c9a84               ; symbol stub for: swift_once
0x1000c7010 <+76>:  adrp   x8, 1365
0x1000c7014 <+80>:  ldr    x8, [x8, #1464]
0x1000c7018 <+84>:  ldr    x9, [sp, #16]
0x1000c701c <+88>:  str    x9, [x8]
0x1000c7020 <+92>:  bl     0x1000c6cb4               ; type metadata accessor for APPNAME.AppDelegate at AppDelegate.swift
0x1000c7024 <+96>:  bl     0x1004c820c               ; symbol stub for: NSStringFromClass
0x1000c7028 <+100>: mov    x29, x29
0x1000c702c <+104>: bl     0x1004c83ec               ; symbol stub for: objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
0x1000c7030 <+108>: movz   x8, #0
0x1000c7034 <+112>: ldur   w10, [x29, #-4]
0x1000c7038 <+116>: str    x0, [sp, #8]
0x1000c703c <+120>: mov    x0, x10
0x1000c7040 <+124>: ldr    x1, [sp, #16]
0x1000c7044 <+128>: mov    x2, x8
0x1000c7048 <+132>: ldr    x3, [sp, #8]
0x1000c704c <+136>: bl     0x1004c8104               ; symbol stub for: UIApplicationMain
0x1000c7050 <+140>: movz   w10, #0
0x1000c7054 <+144>: str    w0, [sp, #4]
0x1000c7058 <+148>: mov    x0, x10
0x1000c705c <+152>: mov    sp, x29
0x1000c7060 <+156>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #16
0x1000c7064 <+160>: ret
```

Comment: have you been able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For me a restart if Xcode solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Charles** to grap net packages.